# Can I use a third-party routing service with a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to use Google Maps as the base layer for a project. However, instead of using their Directions API to draw a route on the map, I'd like to use a third-party service. Is this a violation of Google's Terms of Agreement?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use) not coding.

Comment: @geocodezip can you suggest a place to post this question?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-3/info, "Ask non-programming and licensing questions in the Maps API Google Group (see full description for a link)" (although I don't see any link there)

Comment: I added it back in.  The Google Group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-js-api-v3 is still the go-to place for support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google does not prohibit showing third party content (in your case "directions") on a Google map . What it prohibits is showing Google content on an non-Google map as section 10.4.e states in [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions).

So **YOU CAN** use a third party service for directions but you need to watch out for these two points:

- **10.4.c.i)** No creation of a substitute service. You will not use the Service to create a Maps API Implementation that is a substitute for, or substantially similar service to, Google Maps (at https://www.google.com/maps (or such other URL as Google may provide)) ("Google Maps") or the Service.
- **10.4.c.iii)** No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the ToS more closely, Daffi has the correct answer. Please see the answer below me. Thanks!